# how to root access in android emulator

Tags: android

When I write su in terminal emualator. I have su:uid 10032 not allowed to su.
What Can I do to root the emulator to have access?

Comment: Hi, I reply to a similar question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain root access via su on the Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687082/obtain-root-access-via-su-on-the-android-emulator)